# Add page title to drupal formatter

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, formatter

I want to add the page title to my e-mail subject line within a drupal formatter.

Below is my code but I do not understand why it does not work. Can somebody point me in the right direction?

I have some very basic php knowledge but Drupal is quite new to me.

Thanks in advance

```
if (isset($variables['#items'][0]['email'])) {
  $mail = $variables['#items'][0]['email'];
  $subject = $variables[node:title];
  print l(t('Heb je een vraag over deze opleiding'), "mailto:{$mail}?subject={$subject}", array('class' => array('nme-button', 'ask-about-course')));
}
```

The token I used probably is not correct (any clues on how I can find the correct one?). I was wondering if the rest of my code is okay? What does $variables do and ['#items'][0]['email'] and do I need  this for calling my page title?

Comment: `$variables[node:title]` would be the problem, but it's impossible to know where you should get the node object from without knowing the context you're in...where is this code exactly?

Comment: On a course page: http://www.syntra-limburg.be/opleidingen/faceliftmassage How can I find what context this is? 

These pages are generated using an XML import. So I assume Drupal imports the xml's and creates nodes and then tags them as courses.